# Use FontChooser and Undo-Redo Commands

Tags: java, swing, undo

I am creating a Notepad in java i need help as we know there is a Font chooser option in notepad i want to add that option in my notepad as well but FontChosser class is also not avaible and what should do for Undo,Redo Buttons as well

Comment: [Font chooser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2120228/java-swing-font-chooser); [`UndoManager`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/undo/UndoManager.html)

Comment: Font chooser class is of which package

Comment: Did you follow the links?